# sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split for rows, not columns

Tags: python, testing, scikit-learn, rows, training-data

I have a DataFrame 32*5:

[image]

I want select rows from 1 to 31 as X(independent values) and row 32 as Y(dependent value).

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(dff3.iloc[1:32, 1:6].values, dff3.iloc[-1, 1:6].values, test_size = 0.25)
```

but I think it select columns as X, and compare columns, not rows.

and shows Error: `Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples`.

how can I define rows as X?

thanks

Comment: It seems you want to [transpose the dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), but if that is the only data you have, you may headed for trouble with so many independent variables and so few samples.

Comment: I think by using Lasso or PCA (econometric) methods for decreasing Xs, will not be trouble. am I right?

Comment: Maybe. The potential problem with so many independent variables and so few samples is that MANY model parameters will "fit" the target without being an accurate model.  You'll need to evaluate how good your model is.